# browser independent readonly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way in HTML, JavaScript or jQuery to make an **input** element "readonly", i.e.

- the user can read it
- the user can copy its content to the clipboard
- the user can't change it

that will work in all browsers? I know there is a "readonly" attribute but it's not supported in all browsers.

I'm not asking about security aspects, just user experience.

Comment: +1 just to see those those pretty unicorns

Comment: @Slurpie It is supported in all current browsers. What you need is a fix for IE8 and below... (let's say it as it is)

Comment: I want it to work in all browsers in common use

Comment: Why "not supported"? MSDN says it's defined in HTML 4 and DOM level 1 -- don't they support it by now? (disclaimer: I 'm just asking, I don't know)

Comment: and so what do what happens when javascript off then they are no longer readonly ?

Comment: @Slurpie What version of IE do you have on your system? Does the readonly attribute work on it? You can test here: http://jsfiddle.net/9XLYc/1/

Comment: @Slurpie http://www.google.com/images?q=unicorn

Comment: @Slurpie It appears that the `readonly` attribute is supported in all versions of IE: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/input/readonly

Comment: Hmmm... I distinctly remember some browser version not supporting it...

Answer (score 6):

if you using jQuery (as you put in tag) it cross-browser:

```
$(...your input ...).attr('readonly','readonly');
```

edit: from http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp

> The readonly attribute is supported in
>   all major browsers.

Comment: So are you saying that jQuery does more than just set the "readonly" attribute?  It actually makes it work in browsers that don't support the "readonly" attribute in HTML?

Comment: Does this allow users to copy the text as well?

Comment: @Slurpie - provide examples browser that not support it

Comment: Woe to you oh earth and sea -- they see the `$` in front and they upvote. On the other hand, it may be the unicorns that do it.

Comment: @Jon I always blame unicorns when someone else is more successful than me.

Comment: @Slurpie It seems that the `readonly` attribute is supported in all versions of IE: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/input/readonly

Comment: @Jon +1 for god eye and catch copy&paste -> fixed

Comment: @bensiu: You put up the w3schools link as an argument *for* your answer? http://www.w3fools.com

Comment: Is there a non-w3schools source for browser support of "readonly"?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to fake it:

```
<p class="fake_input">The readonly Value</p>
<input type="hidden" name="real_input" value="The readonly Value" />
```

And if you wanted it to *look* like a disabled input box, you could style it and stuff.

Just remember that people can change hidden inputs willy nilly.

Comment: hidden is hidden for users -> not copyable

Comment: @bensiu That's why you have the paragraph that people can see.

Comment: @Slurpie You could use images or tables, but most people these days use [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) to style their markup.

Comment: @Slurpie What do you want it to look like?

Comment: @Slurpie What does a readonly textbox look like? I'm not being intentionally obtuse; in Chrome and IE, a readonly textbox looks like a normal textbox. But that would be a UX nightmare. People would think your site was broken if it *looked* like they could edit something, but then it refused to change.

Answer (score 1):

Although the readOnly attribute is case insensitive in html it must be written 'readOnly' in js. It works when directly assigned in all browsers from and including IE6, but the way you assign it can be browser specific.

element.setAttribute('readOnly','readOnly') does not work in older browsers,
but element.readOnly='readOnly' (or any truthy value') works x-browser.

Comment: what about setting it in jQuery or HTML?

Comment: Thanks @kennebec! This was doing my head in. @JoelFan - yes, it's true in jQuery too.